# Run Test on another node if dedicated node is occupied in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to overcome a problem of configuring the test runs for the below Scenarios on Jenkins:

- I have setup a test run ( Automation Suite1 ) as a job1 on jenkins to run on node1.
- I have setup a test run ( Automation Suite2 ) as a job2 on jenkins server to run on node2.
- I have setup other nodes also like node3,node4 which are configured for job3 and job4 respectively.

Problem: When node1 is occupied by running job1, job2 has to wait till the job1 completes on that node1, But node3,node4 are free as jobs3 and jobs4 are completed at that time. I want to utlize node3 or node4 for job2 when node1 is occupied by job1.

How to configure such scenarios in Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this using || operator between the nodes.

Eg: node1 || node2

```
Restrict where this project can be run
Label Expression:  node1 || node2
```